# Powershell -match with variable in pattern

Tags: powershell, match

Hoping an experienced coder could explain why a variable create from contents of a text file and added to a match pattern does not work...but a variable with a static string does?

```
$computer = "TYMXL-F3MC012WV"

$s_01 =  (Get-Content $path\source_files\pascodes.txt -Raw).replace("`n","|") #F3MC|FRSE|FGTS
$s_02 = "F3MC|FRSE|FGTS"

$computer -match "^(TYMX|MPLS)(W|L|T|V)-($s_01)([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}).+$" #false
$computer -match "^(TYMX|MPLS)(W|L|T|V)-($s_02)([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}).+$" #true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text file likely uses CRLF (`` "`r`n" ``) newlines rather than LF-only (`` "`n" ``) newlines, so that replacing just the latter isn't enough.

A simple way to avoid this problem is to not use `-Raw`, so that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) returns an *array* of lines, which you can the join with `|`:

```
$s_01 = (Get-Content $path\source_files\pascodes.txt) -join '|'
```

Note that `Get-Content` recognizes CRLF and LF newlines interchangeably, as does PowerShell in general.

---

While you *could* fix your original attempt as follows, the above solution is much simpler (while it is slower, that won't matter with small files):

```
$s_01 = (Get-Content $path\source_files\pascodes.txt -Raw).Trim() `
          -replace '\r?\n' , '|'
```

- The regex `\r?\n` used with the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) above matches both CRLF and LF newlines.
- `.Trim()` is applied first in order to remove any *trailing* newline, so that it doesn't also get replaced with `|`; note that this trims all leading and trailing whitespace; to trim just a single trailing newline, use `-replace '\r?\n\z'` instead (before applying the `-replace` operation above).

Comment: mklement0, Thanks for taking the time in explaining in why mine will not work and how yours does.. I included your examples below to show others how there are multiple ways of using a list of values in a text file and creating a logical 'or' group to place in a regex pattern.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry all...have no idea how to add code tags...even with help example...but answers provides above both work in my situation...and looks like i inadertently deleted your comment mklement0...meant no disrespect

Comment: @BorisPumpernickel, re my deleted comment: No worries at all: I deleted it myself once I knew you had seen it (I appreciated your nice feedback and wanted to acknowledge it, but I figured the comment had served its purpose once you had read it).

Comment: @BorisPumpernickel, as for formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - in short: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks, and you cannot _double_ `\`` instances - use `\\`` to embed `\``.